# What is the definition of a height function for a subsurface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, morse-theory

What is the definition of a height function for a subsurface? Is a height function exactly a Morse function?

In the [paper](https://sci-hub.se/10.1515/crll.2000.028):

"On the Teichmüller tower of mapping class
groups
By Allen Hatcher at Ithaca, Pierre Lochak at Paris and Leila Schneps."

we have:

"A picture of the subsurface with  $\pm f_{t u}$ as the **height function** is shown in figure  11."

Comment: The height function associated to an embedded in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with coordinates $(x,y)$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^n. y\in\mathbb{R}$, of a topological space $T$ is the function $(x,y)\mapsto y$ restricted to $T$.

Comment: @BenMcKay . Where is reference of this definition ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a topological space $T$ embedded in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Denote each point of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ as $(x,y)$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$.
The *height function* associated to that embedded is the restriction to $T$ of the function $(x,y)\mapsto y$. As a reference, see John Milnor, **Morse Theory**, Annals of Mathematics Studies, Princeton, 1969, p. 2, and again in Figure 3.3, although he only gives an example where $T$ is the torus. By the Whitney embedding theorem, every smooth function on any manifold is a height function for some smooth embedding.